# What folder should I put my new OpenCV(4.5.1 verison) in Pycharm to use?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

Pycharm(3.9) has only opencv-python 4.4.0. But it is buggy when I need to use someting else. So I want to use 4.5.1 or 3.4.4 version of OpenCV. I wanted to learn how to use one of these two versions.

I am appreciate from now thank you all

Comment: To use 4.5.1 you have to build opencv from source, specifying the path to your python environment.

Comment: if you download source code from git repo then source code you can put wherever you want. And then you need C/C++ compiler for this. Maybe in repo you get script which will install it in expected folder - but it need to put in Python folder, not in PyCharm folder. PyCharm is only IDE/Editor.